# parse online JSON into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to get some JSON and at the key of "1" in that JSON, trying to convert that value, which is an array to a javascript array.

Here is my code so far, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
var data = 'http://hawttrends.appspot.com/api/terms/';
var results = [];
$.getJSON(data, function (json) {
  console.log(json["1"]);
});
```

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: That isn't JSONP.  You can't do that.

Comment: What is the Content-Type of the response? If not application/json or text/json, you need to `eval()` the response to get a JS object.

Comment: what does `json` look like?

Comment: What Json? Without knowing what your Json looks we can't help.

Comment: This page doesn't seem to be served with the necessary CORS headers

Comment: @DanielA.White There's the URL in the question : http://hawttrends.appspot.com/api/terms/

Comment: @dystroy why should i have to browse there?

Comment: So we should click on a random link in the question now @dystroy?

Comment: You can't just call arbitrary URLs from JavaScript.  The URL needs to support CORS or JSONP.  Check the docs to see if this API supports one of those.  If it doesn't then you *can't* access it via JavaScript.  You'd need to make a proxy on your websever that you'd call to get the data.

Comment: What URL are you trying to access the hawttrends.appspot page from? This might be a same origin policy block that is preventing you from even getting the JSON. In that case, you need to use JSONP.